# how to disable all the exceptions using _controlfp_s in visual studio

Tags: c++, exception

I want to disable all the exceptions using _controlfp_s in visual studio, I am doing some floating point operation and before that operation I would like to disable all the exceptions, please suggest it with example.

Thanks,

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C++, Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10.

Comment: I have tried following approach but it didn't work.

unsigned int control_word;
int err;
_controlfp_s(&control_word, _MCW_EM, _MCW_EM);
_controlfp_s(0, _MCW_EM, _MCW_EM);